# Parse JSON from Named Values in policy

Tags: azure-api-management

I would like to store a JSON document in a Named Value.  Then in my inbound policy, I want to access this JSON and use it to construct a header.

So for example, I want to store in a Named Value called `Info`, a document like:

```
{ "Info": "MyInfo" }
```

Then write a policy like:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="MyVar" value={{Info}}>
    <set-header name="MyHeader" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{
            string headerValue;
            // Parse the JSON in "MyVar" and use it set
            // "headerValue" to the string "MyInfo"
            return headerValue;
        }</value>
    </set-header>
</inbound>
```

What code should I write instead of the comment in the policy above? I can't figure out how to:

- access the variable "MyVar"
- parse its JSON value to extract the string "MyInfo"

Comment: Turn the comment into code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API Management policy expression

```
string myVarValue = context.Variables["MyVar"]?.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myVarValue))
{
   JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(myVarValue);
   string myInfoValue = jsonObject["Info"]?.ToString();
   return myInfoValue;
}
return null;
```

You can check all the .NET Framework types allowed in policy expressions in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#CLRTypes)